# Balance of activities

Tags: macroeconomics

Can you explain why the current account of a country is a relevant indicator for the stability of its economic development? I read about this but do not exactly see the link that qualifies it as a indicator.

Afteredit:

Wikipedia says this:

A current account surplus indicates that the value of a country's net foreign assets (i.e. assets less liabilities) grew over the period in question, and a current account deficit indicates that it shrank.

I do not understand why these points say us something about the stability of the development. (Sorry, that I didn't manage to express clearly from the beginning but I'm no native speaker.)

Is my problem now more evident?

Greetings Rico

Comment: What do you mean by a "balance of activities"?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I mean by that what also might be called current account of a state (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_account).

Comment: Now that you've found the Wikipedia article on current account, shouldn't the Overview section already answer your question? If not, please edit your question and make it more specific.

Comment: Herr K. did you see my changes?

Comment: Might someone else help me?